# How to add a value to already existing value in column field and then insert the update value into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have a `members` table with a column `amount` which already has an integer value in it, I wish to add to that value and then use its contents to update another table called `accounts` which holds the amount being credited and the new balance (i.e After addition)

```
   $this->query_array = array(':amt' =>  $amount, ':uid' => $userid, ':dat' => $date );

    $this->query_string = "UPDATE members SET amount = amount + :amt;
                           INSERT INTO accounts VALUES ( :uid, :amt, members.amount + :amt,  :dat);";
```

Thats my query above, am trying to get the `members.amount` table from the `update` query and use it in the `insert` query is there a better way, one that works than what I tried.

Sample Data :

```
         Members Table      userid       amount
                             ---------------------
                               u123        4000
                               y123        5000

          Accounts Table      userid       credit   balance    date
```

`Accounts table` is currently empty so what I wanna do is add 300 to all values in memebrs table and then insert into accounts something like this.

```
          Accounts Table      userid       credit   balance    date
                              -------------------------------------
                                u123       300      4300       11-11-11
                                y123       300      5300       11-11-11
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an [insert ... select ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement to achieve the desired outputs:

```
INSERT INTO accounts
SELECT members.userid, :amt, members.amount,  :dat FROM members
```

Notes:

1. I'm using the `members.amount` in place of `members.amount + :amt` because the `:amt` has already been added once to `members.amount`.
2. Your update statement updates all records within the `members` table, yet the insert statement would create records for a specific user only. I believe you should restrict the update statement to the specific user only or not restrict the insert to a specific user. I chose the latter approach.
3. If you want to store the balance in a denormalised way, then I would rather use a trigger on the accounts table to update the balance in the members table, than to use 2 statements.

Comment: I also have to update the members table from 4000 to 4300 first before `INSERT` so I am in no way selecting.

Comment: Yeah, you have your update statement for that. I thought you had an issue with the insert based on the question.

Comment: Okay I just inserted your solution right under my update and it works. Sorry for misjudging the solution

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple insert by a select query, the only question is about the date

```
INSERT INTO Accounts (userid, credit, balance, date)
  SELECT userid, 300, amount, NOW()
    FROM Members;
```